# PyTest Matplotlib Figure Appears on Show

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, testing, pytest

I have a complicated method called `plotter()` which processes some data and produces a matplotlib plot with several components. Due to its complexity I simply want to test that the plot appears. This will confirm that all of the data is processed reasonably and that something gets shown without any errors being thrown. I am not looking to run an image comparison as that's not currently possible for this project.

My function is too complicated to show here, so the following example could be considered instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plotter():
    x = np.arange(0,10)
    y = 2*x
    fig = plt.plot(x, y)

plotter()
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to use PyTest to simply assert that a figure appears? If not then solutions using other test frameworks would also be greatly appreciated.

(For context I am using Python 3.)

Comment: Usually the only reason for a figure not to appear is that an error occurs. Hence it using exactly the `plotter` as test should be fine, `def test_plotter(): plotter()`.

Comment: For the updated question, `def test_plotter(): plotter(); plt.show()`

Comment: Thanks, apologies for not replying and just updating the question; I'm on a very tight deadline and have pushed this particular issue to the side. I did try your suggestion but when I run pytest the figure appears, so it then needs to be closed before the rest of the tests can be ran. I wanted to avoid this but can't find a way to suppress the image while still calling plt.show().

Comment: Yes, if you want to test if the figure shows it must be shown. However maybe it's enough for you to test if the figure can be drawn or saved? `plt.draw()`, `plt.savefig(..)`. Reasons that a figure which is successfully drawn or saved would not be shown are backend specific anyways.